# eclipse delete servlet with web.xml entries

Tags: eclipse, servlets

am using Eclipse's New->Servlet wizard thereby having auto-generated servlet and servlet-mapping entries ready for me. But when I select a servlet's java file and delete it, the corresponding entries in web.xml don't get deleted.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine just edit the `web.xml` file and delete the entries. It's likely by design that they are not automatically deleted when you delete the servlet.

Comment: I wonder why its like that. Makes no sense to me. If eclipse can add servlet mappings automatically when you do `project > right click > new > servlet`, then it should also be able to remove mappings when a servlet is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Annotations? You don't have to take care of any configuration in web.xml for this.

```
package com.inventwheel.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DeleteMe
 */
@WebServlet(description = "DeleteMe Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/DeleteMe" })
public class DeleteMe extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DeleteMe() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: How does annotations help in this case ? I deleted a sevlet and did build project and nothing happend. The servlet had all the auto generated annotations you mentioned.

Comment: Actually when you are using annotation you don't need to maintain any web.xml file. All the configuration parameter can be set using annotation in the servlet itself.